# SSRS Constant group height

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

In my report I have a group with an inner detail group.

```
Group
     details
more of the group
```

I need 3 groups on each page and I need each one to be lined up correctly. Each group member can have between 1 and 4 rows. When there are 4 rows for each one, they line up perfectly, however when there are less, everything shifts up.

Is there a way to define a static height for the group so that if there are less than 4 rows, it pads with whitespace so the bottom section of the group is in the same place?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a blank row whenever your details are less than 4 rows. Try mo make an iif condition in your details row expression textbox.

Comment: Thank you. This approach worked for me. I created a new dataset which got the count of rows associated with each id (group), then I used the Lookup function in the hidden property for the blank rows to determine how many should be hidden.

Is there a way to use something like RowCount where not isNothing(Fields!text.value) so i do not need the additional dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the table within a rectangle. Keep the height of the rectangle to the height that you want(height of 4 rows). This way, if the table is having less rows, the height of the rectangle will still be maintained.

So, if u put each of the tables in a rectangle and define it as above, I think it should work. Always works for me when I already know the maximum row count.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have only one table which has an outside group and inside group.